# python seaborn FutureWarning - does not show plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm running python 3.6.1 on Anaconda.
Whenever I try plotting with seaborn, I get the following warning.

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py:1428: FutureWarning: remove_na is deprecated and is a private function. Do not use.
  stat_data = remove_na(group_data)
```

even if I try with the barplot example posted on the page below,
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

I still get the same result.

Thanks in advance.

---

I simplified the code. But the result is the same as well

[this is the same code from https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html ]

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

Comment: Is that an error? It looks like it's just a deprecation warning, not an exception. Does your code run?

Comment: oh yeah.. I guess it's not an error.. better change my words..

Comment: anyways, the plot is not shown. But the other codes below the specific seaborn code is run properly

Comment: That might be a problem in your code. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: I've posted it THX

Comment: Do you have to do something extra to display the plot, like in [this example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/distplot_options.html)?

Comment: not at all. The code that I posted is the only thing I need

Comment: Well, if it's not working, something must be missing.

Comment: I wonder what could that be.. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Aug 2017.  It was triggered by Seaborn calling a private function in Pandas.

See [Pandas ticket](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16971) and [Seaborn ticket](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/1241).  Update your Seaborn and this warning should go away.

Answer (score 0):

urp.. I left out the plt.show() code.. What an absurd thing to do..

My problem of the plot not showing up was resolved with the following code added,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

However, the FutureWarning message still crops up. Please DO post an answer if anyone knows how to deal with it.

Thank you very much

Comment: That’s what I was talking about in my comment.